# Re-render view when property changes

Tags: ember.js

I have the following view to display a checked mark whenever the `active` property is set:

```
App.ActiveEntryView = Ember.View.extend({

    render: function(buffer) {
        var active = this.get('active'), icon;
        if (active) {
            icon = 'fa fa-check';
        } else {
            icon = '';
        }
        return buffer.push(icon);
    }

});
```

But this is not re-rendering if I the `active` property changes. This is bound in my template like this:

```
{{#each model}}
    <tr class="odd-even">
        ....
        <td>{{view App.ActiveEntryView activeBinding="parked"}}</td>
        ....
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Where `parked` is the property of the model that I want to evaluate. But whenever that property changes in the model, the view is not re-rendered. I have tried adding an observer:

```
App.ActiveEntryView = Ember.View.extend({

    render: function(buffer) {
        var active = this.get('active'), icon;
        if (active) {
            icon = 'fa fa-check';
        } else {
            icon = '';
        }
        return buffer.push(icon);
    }.observes('active')

});
```

But then I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Referring to the line:

```
        return buffer.push(icon);
```

I guess that the observer triggers the render function passing a different parameter than `buffer`.

How can I re-render the view then?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a ton about views, but from what I understand, this isn't the way to go about re-rendering. Specifically, `render` is a hook called by the system when it needs to render the template. Calling the hook yourself won't force the system to re-render the template, that has to be done at a higher level.

That being said, there's probably a way to force a re-render of the whole view, but that doesn't seem like a good solution for most issues. I see that you're doing something with icons, so I'm going to take a wild stab at a solution without knowing your entire problem. If you post more details, I can probably help you more.

From what I can tell, it seems like you're trying to change the icon of an element in the view when the `active` property changes. Here's how you might do that:

In your view template:

```
<i {{bind-attr class='view.active:fa view.active:fa-check'}}></i>
```

You can see more details about binding class names [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-class-names/).